# Microsoft graph is remembering the user after authentication

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft graph in my Android project to authenticate users. 
I'm doing so via this method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-android

after a successful login Microsoft remembers the user email, so next time when user is trying to login it will suggest to use a previously logged in account. If user chooses a previously used email, a password is not required.

[image]

Problem raises when we have a single device where multiple users need to login via Microsoft. In this case new user will see the email of previously logged users and can select their email and log into account without entering any password. 
My question is how can I avoid this behavior and close the session after each login?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell ADAL to request credentials again by switching [`PromptBehavior`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/blob/cfdb40c5d0fb28e4825df030e909bc493aaaffe9/adal/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal/PromptBehavior.java) from `Auto` to `Always`:

```java
// Perform authentication requests
mAuthContext.acquireToken(
    getActivity(),
    RESOURCE_ID,
    CLIENT_ID,
    REDIRECT_URI,
    PromptBehavior.Always,
    getAuthInteractiveCallback());
```

Comment: Thank you Marc!  This will remove the suggestion in the bottom of the snap.

Comment: Thank you @iDesignerzone. I had the same question too